# Proving nested interval theorem from least upper bound property of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove nested interval theorem (intersection of nested bounded intervals is non-empty) using least upper bound property of real number set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[a_i,b_i]$, $i\in I$ be a family of nested intervals, i.e. for $i,j\in I$ we have $[a_i,b_i]\subseteq [a_j,b_j]$ or $[a_i,b_i]\supseteq [a_j,b_j]$.
Let $X=\bigcap_{i\in I}[a_i,b_i]$.
If $I=\emptyset$, then $X=\mathbb R\ne \emptyset$.
So assume $I\ne \emptyset$ and we can pick $\iota\in I$.
The $b_\iota$ is an upper bound for the nonempty set $S:=\{\,a_i\mid i\in I\,\}$.
By the Least Upper Bound property, let $s$ be the least upper bound of $S$.
Then $s\ge a_i$ for all $i\in I$ by definition.
If $i\in I$, then $b_i$ is also an upper bound for $S$, hence $s\le b_i$.
We conclude $s\in X$.

Comment: But to have a number $s$ between all  $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s, the least upper bound property is not necessary. Am I correct ?

Comment: @prasenjit: No, but something is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

Let $\bigl([a_\iota,b_\iota]\bigr)_{\iota\in I}$ be the given family of intervals. Consider the numbers $\alpha:=\sup_{\iota\in I}a_\iota$ and $\beta:=\inf_{\iota\in I} b_\iota$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a sequence of nested intervals $[a_n,b_n]$. Then the supremum of the numbers $a:=\sup\{a_n\}$ exists and belongs to all the intervals. Is this answer enough for you to work out the details?